# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log(n^3-7)}{n^2+2n}$ using the comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble with this series. I know I have to use the comparison test but I don't exactly know how or to which series I can compare it to?

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log(n^3-7)}{n^2+2n}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the following elementary facts: first, the terms in the sum are all positive. Then
$$\frac{\log(n^3-7)}{n^2+2n} \le \frac{\log(n^3)}{n^2+2n} \le \frac{\log(n^3)}{n^2}$$
by monotonicity of the logarithm function. Lastly, we use $\log(n^3) = 3 \log(n)$ and observe that for all $x \ge 4$ we have $\log(x) \le \sqrt{x}$ (which is true by comparing derivatives: $\frac 1x \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$ for all $x \ge 4$ and at $x=4$ we have $\log(2) < 2 = \sqrt 4$). Plugging this in implies

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log(n^3-7)}{n^2+2n} \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{3 \sqrt n}{n^2} = 3\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\frac 32}}$$
and the last series is a known convergent series. By the comparison test the original series also converges.

Comment: Maybe note that the convergent series is $\zeta(\frac{3}{2})$? Fractional inputs in the zeta function aren't really common, so this is pretty interesting. +1 for your answer.